# Alamofire not working after upgrading (Swift/Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xcode8

My earlier version of swift was in 2.2. 
I have updated Alamofire using different options like

1. pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
2. pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => '3.5.0'

Whenever I open the workspace, it asks to convert to latest, I opted for swift 2.3. But the Xcode shows the errors below:

- Header 'Alamofire-Swift.h' not found
- Could not build Objective-C module 'Alamofire'

and inside Alamofire
Cannot convert value of type 'SecTrustResultType' to expected argument type 'UInt32'

I have deleted the files under the folders ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and build again . Same errors display.

What may be the wrong thing I did ?

Comment: Why don't you go with Swift 3?

Comment: did with swift 3 now.. Still same issues a and b. also 64 issues under alamofire
eg: Pods/Alamofire/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift:248:32: Editor placeholder in source file


Pods/Alamofire/Source/Manager.swift:107:38: Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'String'

Pods/Alamofire/Source/Manager.swift:513:17: Value of type 'Request.TaskDelegate' has no member 'urlSession' 

etc.

Comment: I would suggest you'd better remove `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'` then `pod install` then add it back, run `pod install` again.

Comment: did the steps by William, first removed then again added, but same issues again.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: No  Llg, I have installed older version Xcode in my machine. Now my machine has both 8 and 7.2

Answer (score 4):

As per [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#cocoapods) documentation it will work only with :

> CocoaPods 1.1.0+ is required to build Alamofire 4.0.0+.

I followed following steps and it's working fine :

Open your terminal -

1. sudo gem update --system
2. sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods --pre (It will install prerelease version [1.1.0.rc.3](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases) because final version not came yet)
3. pod setup
4. pod repo update
5. remove all pods of your project and install it again ( Comment pod names by # -> Do **pod update** and again by removing # -> Do **pod update** )

Comment: I have removed all pods. followed your steps again installed Alamofire
I used following lines to remove the pod
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod clean
$ rm Podfile

but it shows 522  errors  "Definition conflicts with previous value.  Is there any additional steps that should follow?

Comment: I have tried it. Still I have lot of errors in Alamofire along with previous header error.